# Unexpected finish when linking static library

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 to compile library. I've used CMake to build Visual Studio Solution, and then I've built library.lib file, which is static library.. Then I have two different situations:

1) I've left library.lib file where studio placed it.
2) I' ve moved library to MyProjectLocation/Libs/

Then I link library to my Qt project.

In first situation everything works fine. In second situation program exits unexpectedly. Debugger does not show line of code, where crash happened - it closes.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 + WDK + Qt msvc2013 32bit opengl

So question is: "Why second situation provides so strange behaviour?"

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you are not linking the debug version of library with the release version.

Comment: Yes, I am. Also, if I've done this I would not have "Program closed unexpectedly", but something like "Debug field in library does not match Release field in program".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so i fixed this problem, adding .dll to folder with .lib file. It seems to be, that .lib file was only headers(I've wondered why it is 13 kB), and it needed .dll file.